# failed to load source for

Tags: php

I have a php project which used to work well, yesterday it suddenly failed, from the login page i cannot actually get into the system with the right username/password. i checked it in Firebug, it said: failed to load source for the php file that's supposed to load after login.what could be wrong? anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript calls or are you doing a `header("Location:...")` in your script? Without the error message or some more details it is hard to say.

Comment: yeah, i m doing header("Location:dashboard.php') in my script.

Comment: Check the server logs...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all your dependencies?

- Is the file loaded after login still there and still containing the correct code?
- Is the code that points to that script still pointing to the correct file?